# MS[OE] activity (before the split and after)

Tags: discussion, statistics, participation

A request for stats (or something to look at).

One of the perceptions (it may be correct or not) is that smaller Stack Exchange sites have things shouted down by Stack Overflow regulars who are unfamiliar with how some issues are issues on smaller sites that really don't raise to a prominent issue on SO (example is the recently created auto-protect of questions that get low rep answers in a timeframe).  Note that's only an example of how there is some difference between a small graduated site and SO.

What I would like to see (or at least for people to look into and keep in their back of their mind) is information on MSO and ultimately MSE participation.

**For the period of one month before and after the split, what percent of activity is from each site on the SE network?**

MS[OE] activity is determined by "more than 2 questions, 2 answers, 10 comments, or 50 votes in the time period" `(or 2-questions 2-answers 10-comments 50 votes)`

Graduated site activity is determined by "1000 reputation and 10 days of login and more than 2 questions, 2 answers, 10 comments or 50 votes" `(and 10-login-days 1000-reputation (or 2-questions 2-answers 10-comments 50-votes))`

Beta sites ??? (I'm not active enough on any to really say "this is a starting point for saying someone is active")

I am primarily interested in how representative the sites other than Stack Overflow are in the meta discussion about the SE network as a whole.

Please feel free to alter this question/request in a way that presents more useful data.  It's meant as a starting point for the discussion about the representation of different sites on MS[OE].  After the split, these stats may come in useful for information about how to encourage more participation on MSE from other sites.

Comment: I don't think the meta people are discriminatory, they'll shout down anything they disagree with, from any site

Comment: @RichardTingle The point is people will shut down feature requests that would only benefit small SE sites, because they're all from SO, where that feature wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: @RichardTingle its not an issue of discrimination but rather that "these aren't our problems" with only familiarity with Stack Overflow and unaware how they impact the sites that get 20-40 questions/day rather than 8k questions/day. When someone is only familiar with Stack Overflow, these suggestions may not seem important or completely inconsequential to how things work and thus get lost in the activity of MSO / SO users.

Comment: @RichardTingle I agree with you that folks will downvote anything they don't agree with but I don't think *this* is the problem. I think the perceived issue is like this. A) Smaller sites have needs and problems that differ from SO's needs and problems. B) People who are used to SO but not to smaller sites do not know these issues. So they disagree with posts that *they might very well agree with **if** they had experience on the smaller sites*.

Comment: *"One of the perceptions (it may be correct or not) is that smaller SE sites have things shouted down by Stack Overflow regulars [...]"* ... Is that a prevalent perception? What are sources that state so?

Comment: Keep in mind that there's a very weak correlation between votes on feature requests and probability of being implemented.  Just because a lot of people vote down a request doesn't mean SE won't consider addressing the problem, and a very high vote count doesn't mean they'll implement the feature.  SE also tends to consider wider ramifications in more detail than your average MSO users (because of course it's their job to do that).

Comment: It feels like they're getting beaten when they rush to the head of state (MSO) instead of talking first with their local councillor (child meta), where the level of need is judged on national vs local scope

Comment: @Servy I'm not interested in the votes, but rather the *participation* itself.  Are there some sites where people don't even show up on SO unless there was a blog posting about some change  coming up (thats already been discussed for a month)?  For example, does anyone at... Bicycles.SE or Travel.SE know that questions will be auto protected when 5 people with rep less than 10 answer it in a 24h period? How will this affect them? Where was this discussed prior? Why was this done? Is there more participation after the split from these smaller SE sites than before?

Comment: @MichaelT My guess is SO has the *smallest* percentage of users that are active on meta, given that it has several orders of magnitude more users.  The odds of any given SO user being aware of the latest MSO updates is *much* lower, simply because on the smaller sites it takes just a few users (like, say, just the elected mods and a couple of high rep users) being active to have a respectable percentage.

Comment: @Bart question doesn't say anything about perceptions being _prevalent_, why do you try to bring it on here? as for _sources_, how about this: [1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14808262#14808262 "isn't it amazing how much thought, effort and care is invested into tuning of Stack Overflow...") -> [2](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14808264#14808264 "Per my reading, this sends a pretty strong signal to smaller site communities...")? or [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/823/what-do-you-think-of-the-stack-exchange-main-meta-site)?

Comment: @Servy Interesting and important distinction.  Theres the "Of a percent of the site how active on MSO" which is something additional to the bit that would be interesting.  I was more thinking along the lines of "As a percent of MSO actives, how active are the various sites".

Comment: @gnat if the premise of your post is what was stated, why is it so strange to ask for references to it? If that would indeed be the case, it's interesting (to me at least) information. So I don't see what your problem is. (P.s. I'll add your two statements to my count. I'll take them as a +1 though)

Comment: @Bart it is only strange to me that you are trying to bring _prevalence_ in there, I really can't see how this is relevant to the question asked. As for the references, it looks reasonable that you ask about these, there you go, [in my prior comment](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/823/what-do-you-think-of-the-stack-exchange-main-meta-site)